# Understanding Rudin Theorem 3.3(c)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Rudin's Theorem 3.3 states:

> Suppose $\{s_n\}$, $\{t_n\}$ are complex sequences, and $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} s_n = s$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} t_n = t$. Then

> (a) $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(s_n + t_n\right) = s + t$;

> (b) $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} cs_n = cs$,  $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \left(c + s_n\right) = c + s$, for any number $c$;

> (c) $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} s_n t_n = st$;

> (d) $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{s_n} = \frac{1}{s}$, provided $s_n \neq 0$ ($n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$), and $s \neq 0$.

I proved (a) and (b) without trouble. I'm trying to understand his proof of (c). He notes that for any $s$ we have:
$$ 
s_n t_n - st = (s_n - s)(t_n - t) + s(t_n - t) + t(s_n - s).
$$
My first question is: where does this come from? By brute-forcing the right-side, I can tell that this amounts to adding and subtracting $st$, $ts_n$, and $st_n$. But is there another reason why this holds? Rudin calls it an "identity,' but I've never seen it before.

Then, given $\epsilon > 0$, he takes $N_1, N_2$, so that $n \geq N_1$ implies $|s_n - s| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$ and $n \geq N_2$ implies $|t_n - t| < \sqrt{\epsilon}$. So for $n \geq \max(N_1, N_2)$, we have
\begin{align*}
|(s_n - s)(t_n - t) - 0| = |s_n - s||t_n - t| < \sqrt{\epsilon} \cdot \sqrt{\epsilon} = \epsilon, 
\end{align*}
so $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (s_n - s)(t_n - t) = 0$.

Rudin then claims that the remaining terms in the first identity converge to $0$ by using $(a)$ and $b$. The first term converges, as we just proved, and the second and third are scaled versions of $t_n$ and $s_n$, so they converge. (I'm not sure how to word this exactly, since I need to have convergence first to use this identity, but I'm using the identity to prove they converge, so this is a very circular argument. I'm trying to figure out how best to word it.)

With that aside, we have:
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} [(s_n t_n - st) & = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  (s_n - s)(t_n - t) + s(t_n - t) + t(s_n - s)] \\
& = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (s_n - s)(t_n - t) + \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} s (t_n - t) + \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} t(s_n - s) \\
& = 0 + \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (st_n - st) + \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (ts_n - ts) \\
& = s \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}t_n - st + t \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} s_n - ts \\
& = st - st + ts - ts \\
& = 0
\end{align*}
So $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} (s_n t_n - st) = 0$. I'm trying to figure out exactly how this implies the result, because I can't just invoke part (a)/b to break the limit apart, as that requires convergence of $s_n t_n$, which is what I need. I think, however, it can be used to prove the fact directly.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, we use this limit to find $N$ so that for $n \geq N$, we have $|s_n t_n - st| < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$, so $(s_n t_n) \to st$.

As a general principle, am I allowed to just "break it apart," or was that just a coincidence?

I would appreciate any help and any feedback on what I've written above.

Comment: The identity is justified by adding and subtracting the same terms as you pointed out. That is a pretty common strategy for proving facts in analysis. You _can_ actually deduce that $s_n t_n$ converges in a different, but equivalent, way than how you did it. This is because $st$ converges (constant), $s_n t_n - st$ converges (to $0$ as you’ve shown), and $s_n t_n$ is the sum of these two convergent sequences.

Comment: Your method was not a coincidence, in any case. Using the $\varepsilon$-definition for the limit of a sequence, you can prove more generally that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n - a) = 0$ if and only if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$. The absolute value inequality for $\varepsilon$ is actually the _same_ for both limits!

Comment: "Breaking $\lim_{n \to \infty} (s_n t_n - st) = 0$ apart” is justified because $s_n t_n = (s_n t_n - st) + (st)$ is the sum of two convergent sequences, so you can apply (a) directly.

Answer (score 2):

To state that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}(a_nb_n-ab)=0 $$
Is equivalent to stating that for arbitrary $\varepsilon >0$
$$\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n \geq N, \,|(a_nb_n-ab)-0|<\varepsilon$$
but this also coincides with
$$\exists N\in \mathbb{N}:\forall n \geq N, \,|a_nb_n-ab|<\varepsilon$$
which means, by using the definition of limit,
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}a_nb_n = ab$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $s_n=s+d_n$ and $t_n=t+e_n .$ Then Rudin's equality is $$s_nt_n-st=(s+d_n)(t+e_n)-st=d_ne_n+se_n+td_n.$$ The idea is that if $d_n\to 0$ and $e_n\to 0$ then $d_ne_n$ and $se_n$ and $td_n$ all $\to 0.$

For $d_ne_n$ it is simpler to observe that $|d_n|\le 1$ for all but finitely many $n$ (because $d_n\to 0$). So for all but finitely many $n$ we have $|d_ne_n|\le |e_n|,$ which, combined with $e_n\to 0,$ implies $d_ne_n\to 0.$